# Slow upload on same domain

Tags: php, ftp

I'm running `CENTOS 6.3` and `PHP 5.4.9`, using the `PHP FTP commands`.  I'm using this to upload large files from one domain to an FTP account on the same server.

What I've noticed is that the uploads for even small files take a long time to upload: around 10 to 15 seconds. They do eventually upload.  If I use the same script to upload to a different server it uploads fast: under a second.

I can use the same FTP credentials on a different server and they upload fast. Why is FTP from the one domain on the same server slow?

Updated With Script:

```
$ftp_server = "HOST NAME";
$ftp_user_name = "USERNAME";
$ftp_user_pass = "PASSWORD";
$ftp_folder = "/FTP DIRECTORY";
$path = "/testing/";
$file_name = $_FILES["theFile"]["name"];
$source_file = $_FILES["theFile"]["tmp_name"];
$destination_file = $ftp_folder.$path.$file_name;
$destination_path = $ftp_folder.$path;


function uploadFTP($ftp_server, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass, $source_file, $destination_file, $destination_path) {
    $conn_id = @ftp_connect($ftp_server); // set up basic connection
    $login_result = @ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass); // login with username and password
    if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) { // check connection 
        return false;
    } else {
        $check = @ftp_chdir($conn_id, $destination_path); //check to see if folder is there
        if ($check) { 
            $upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file, $source_file, FTP_BINARY); // upload the file
            if (!$upload) { // check upload status
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        } else { 
            $check = @ftp_mkdir($conn_id, $destination_path); //make new folder
            if ($check) {
                $upload = @ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file, $source_file, FTP_BINARY); // upload the file
                if (!$upload) { // check upload status
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

    }
    @ftp_close($conn_id); //close ftp
}
```

Comment: Depending on your ftp address, it's possible that your traffic is having to go outside the router and back in to your network. Try doing a `tracert` from your terminal.

Answer (score 1):

If they're on the same server, why not just copy the files over instead of sending them out, then taking them back in? I think you're clogging up port 21 (FTP) with outbound and inbound connections.

**::EDIT::**

I know this is not code review, but here's a revision with a handful of minor improvements:

```
$ftp_server = "HOST_NAME";
$ftp_user_name = "USERNAME";
$ftp_user_pass = "PASSWORD";
$ftp_folder = "/FTP_DIRECTORY";
$path = "/testing/";
$file_name = $_FILES["theFile"]["name"];
$source_file = $_FILES["theFile"]["tmp_name"];

/**
 * OLD CODE:
 * $destination_file = $ftp_folder . $path . $file_name;
 * $destination_path = $ftp_folder . $path;
 * 
 * NEW CODE:
 * $destination_path = $ftp_folder . $path;
 * $destination_file = $destination_path . $file_name;
 * 
 * REASON FOR CHANGE: Saves you 1 concat, also, 1 less use of ftp_folder and path
 */
$destination_path = $ftp_folder . $path;
$destination_file = $destination_path . $file_name;


function uploadFTP($ftp_server, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass, $source_file, $destination_file, $destination_path) {
    /**
     * OLD CODE: 
     * $conn_id = @ftp_connect($ftp_server); # set up basic connection
     * 
     * REASON FOR CHANGE: There are times to suppress errors, this is not one of them.
     */ 
    $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die('Couldn\'t connect to ' . $ftp_server); # set up basic connection

    /**
     * REASON FOR NO CHANGE: ftp_login throws a warning on failure.
     */
    $login_result = @ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass); # login with username and password

    if (empty($conn_id) || empty($login_result)) { # check connection 
        return false;
    } else {
        /**
         * OLD CODE:
         * $check = @ftp_chdir($conn_id, $destination_path)
         * 
         * REASON FOR CHANGE: $check is redundant
         */
        if (@ftp_chdir($conn_id, $destination_path)) { # check to see if folder is there
            /**
             * OLD CODE:
             * $upload = @ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file, $source_file, FTP_BINARY);
             * 
             * REASON FOR CHANGE: $upload is redundant
             */
            if (ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file, $source_file, FTP_BINARY)) { # upload the file & check upload status
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else { 
            /**
             * OLD CODE:
             * $check = @ftp_mkdir($conn_id, $destination_path);
             * 
             * REASON FOR CHANGE: $check is redundant
             */
            if (@ftp_mkdir($conn_id, $destination_path)) { # make new folder
                /**
                 * OLD CODE:
                 * $upload = @ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file, $source_file, FTP_BINARY);
                 * 
                 * REASON FOR CHANGE: $upload is redundant
                 */
                if (@ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file, $source_file, FTP_BINARY)) { # upload the file & check upload status
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

    }
    ftp_close($conn_id); # close ftp
}
```

Version 2:

```
$ftp_server = "HOST_NAME";
$ftp_user_name = "USERNAME";
$ftp_user_pass = "PASSWORD";
$ftp_folder = "/FTP_DIRECTORY";
$path = "/testing/";
$file_name = $_FILES["theFile"]["name"];
$source_file = $_FILES["theFile"]["tmp_name"];
$destination_path = $ftp_folder . $path;
$destination_file = $destination_path . $file_name;


function uploadFTP($ftp_server, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass, $source_file, $destination_file, $destination_path) {
    $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die('Couldn\'t connect to ' . $ftp_server); # set up basic connection
    $login_result = @ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass); # login with username and password

    if (empty($conn_id) || empty($login_result)) { # check connection 
        return false;
    } else {
        if (@ftp_chdir($conn_id, $destination_path)) { # check to see if folder is there
            /**
             * OLD CODE:
             * if (ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file, $source_file, FTP_BINARY)) { # upload the file & check upload status
             *    return true;
             * } else {
             *    return false;
             * }
             * 
             * REASON FOR CHANGE: DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself). Abstracted code above to function.
             */
             return uploadFTP_ftpPut($conn_id, $destination_file, $source_file);
        } else {
            if (@ftp_mkdir($conn_id, $destination_path)) { # make new folder
                /**
                 * OLD CODE
                 * ...
                 * 
                 * REASON FOR CHANGE: See above.
                 */
                return uploadFTP_ftpPut($conn_id, $destination_file, $source_file);
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

    }
    ftp_close($conn_id); # close ftp
}

function uploadFTP_ftpPut($conn_id, $destination_file, $source_file){
    # upload the file & check upload status
    if (@ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file, $source_file, FTP_BINARY)) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

Version 3 without comments:

```
$ftp_server = "HOST_NAME";
$ftp_user_name = "USERNAME";
$ftp_user_pass = "PASSWORD";
$ftp_folder = "/FTP_DIRECTORY";
$path = "/testing/";
$file_name = $_FILES["theFile"]["name"];
$source_file = $_FILES["theFile"]["tmp_name"];
$destination_path = $ftp_folder . $path;
$destination_file = $destination_path . $file_name;


function uploadFTP($ftp_server, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass, $source_file, $destination_file, $destination_path) {
    $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die('Couldn\'t connect to ' . $ftp_server); # set up basic connection
    $login_result = @ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass); # login with username and password

    if (empty($conn_id) || empty($login_result)) return false; # check connection 

    if (@ftp_chdir($conn_id, $destination_path)) { # check to see if folder is there
         return uploadFTP_ftpPut($conn_id, $destination_file, $source_file);
    } else {
        if (@ftp_mkdir($conn_id, $destination_path)) { # make new folder
            return uploadFTP_ftpPut($conn_id, $destination_file, $source_file);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    # BTW - you never get here :) 
    ftp_close($conn_id); # close ftp
}

function uploadFTP_ftpPut($conn_id, $destination_file, $source_file){
    # upload the file & check upload status
    if (@ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file, $source_file, FTP_BINARY)) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

Comment: Our clients will be using this tool to upload files to our server using a web page instead of a FTP client since many of them have issues using an FTP client.  We want to the port 21 so we don't chew up our bandwidth.

Comment: Have you tried FTPing as a client (from another machine - not the server). I'm not clear on what it would take to clog a port, but I'd imagine if you have up and down stream data flowing through one port simultaneously, it'd go far slower than if you were only uploading through that port? no?

Comment: I can FTP from one server to another with no issue, it works as I planned.  We have two dedicated servers and I can go from one to another but if the script is on the same server it will still upload but very slow.  I've read somewhere that this could be a permissions issue with our version of PHP but I can't find that comment from awhile back.

Comment: I think you just answered your own question. Basically, port 21 is like a 20 foot wide two way street. Each lane is 10 feet wide...but imagine its dynamic - if a 15 foot wide truck is in one lane, the other lane is only 5 feet wide. Now - when you send traffic out and then back in (ftp from server A to server A) - outbound and inbound traffic is only utilizing 10ft (50% connection). Now, if you're only sending traffic in (ftp from server B into A), you're utilizing 20ft of that road for inbound traffic. Now, that's not counting overheads, etc - but its basically of what I'm trying to say.

Comment: And if someone more versed in networking can correct me - please do, but at the least, that's how I understand networks work...basically, you're creating a bottleneck when FTPing data out from server A and back into server A. Whereas that bottleneck does NOT exist if you FTP data from server B into server A.

Comment: OK, that does make sense and thanks for taking the time with offering some code suggestions.

Comment: No problem at all :) try different usage scenarios and determine if bottlenecking is the issue